# Como gravar Valor DWORD(32 Bits)dentro de uma Chave existente?

Tags: vb.net

Estive pesquisando sobre isto pela Web e até que achei por aqui. O conteúdo pela Web sobre isto, pelo que eu vi é pouco demais. Minha dúvida é a seguinte. Como gravar um valor DWORD(32 Bits)dentro de uma Chave existente. Pois eu quero manipulá-la dentro do meu projeto através de um "CheckBox". Alguém tem uma dica de como fazer isto?

Comment: Como assim chave existente? É a chave de uma tabela em um banco de dados? Não entendi o que é essa chave.

Comment: Por exemplo, eu tenho um navegador e quero que o WebBrowser force a renderização para o IE10, aí a Chave existente é esta:
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION" - então eu quero gravar um valor dentro da chave "FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", eu consegui até criar agora, mas preciso fazer com que o "0" não apareça se não não fará efeito na execução. O executável do aplicativo teste é: "Web.net = 10001

Comment: Desculpe de não ter especificado.

Comment: Resolvi! Tinha esquecido minha senha daqui, rsrs...